# Is it legal to covertly record (CCTV) a credit card pin number?

Tags: united-kingdom, security

My local Supermarket (one of the top 3 in the UK) has modified its self-service checkout tills to include a CCTV camera about 1.5 meters vertically above the credit card reader pointing straight downwards at the keypad.
I'm sure there are legitimate reasons for doing this, and the camera can record any potential theft, but at the same time I really can't believe this can be legal? The camera is fixed, the credit card reader is also fixed (it can be angled downwards a bit, but not removed from camera sight). This has got to be a major security breach, I'm sure the images aren't publicly published online, but I'm also pretty sure that the security personal that can view it are underpaid and subjected to only basic background checks.

I know that fixing a camera to record pin-numbers at a bank ATM machine is illegal - this features in occasional news stories, so how can it be legal for a supermarket to do the same thing?

Comment: I don't know the law in the UK, but often intent is an important element of the law.  If the camera is placed with the intent to record PINs so they can be used fraudulently, it's illegal.  But placing a camera in exactly the same spot might be legal if the intent was to catch shoplifters.

Comment: @Nate Eldgredge I'm sure the claimed intention of Morrisons would be prevent theft, but at the same time it does make it stupidly easy for a badly paid security guy to make a few quid on the side selling pin numbers to criminal gangs.

Comment: Failing to prevent crime is not illegal in the same way as actually committing it.

Comment: Most cameras cannot see through hands...

Comment: It's not clear that they are doing this "covertly" as you put it in your title, since as you said, the camera is obvious.

Comment: @Fizz the camera isn't that obvious. I recognise it because of my background in tech, there are no nearby signs warning anyone about this, nor is it labelled as such. It's about 3cm by 4cm. I recon that counts as 'covert'

Comment: I'm sure there signs at the entry in the store that it's video monitored, which gives them legal cover in that respect. Dunno if any regs prohibit them from recording your pin. The CC companies or banks may not be happy about them recording pins though. And they have a lot of clout (see the recent news on Pornhub for instance.)

Comment: Don't attribute to malice what can easily be explained by stupidity. If it bothers you, just ask the store manager about it. Credit Card pin theft is a legal exposure risk for the supermarket and it is in their own best interest to address it.

Comment: @Hilmar - it doesn't bother me that much - I always shield my hand when entering a pin number anyway, however I'm aware I'm in a minority in doing this. I don't think they're attempting to obtain pin numbers themselves, they make healthy profits anyway, but I am concerned they make it to easy for others less honest to steal them.